# Formatting NSString from NSXMLParser

Tags: nsxmlparser

So I have a small project that parses through an XML file.  I am trying to format the string so that it has no indents before or after.

Some of the xml is:

```
  <master_url>
    <base_url>      http://buildmac.ee.ps.edu/~wsn/boin/    </base_url>
<request_task>
<name>request_task</name>
<field>username</field>
</request_task>
...
```

Before format I have:

```
2012-04-30 21:42:34.684 XMLParser[33194:b303] string = 
        http://buildmac.ee.ps.edu/~wsn/boin/
```

This is how I am trying to format it:

```
[nodecontent appendString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
```

Afterward, it only contains a blank string "" in nodecontent.

**It works for every other element except for that webaddress because it is awkwardly indented**

I'm pretty new to Objective C and Xcode so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but none of the posts I looked at fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to make it work.  I did it in 3 messages to remove Tabs, New Lines, and Spaces:

```
string = [[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\n" withString: @""] mutableCopy];
string = [[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\t" withString: @""] mutableCopy];
string = [[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""] mutableCopy];
```

Note: string is an NSMutableString